# CSS error in Safari 8.0.8 but not in 9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, css, html

What are the main differences for writing CSS for Magento 1.9.2.4 in both versions of Safari? I searched the Internet but can't get proper documentation.

The reason I ask this is because of the following issue:

When I visit the site in Safari 8.0.8 I see:

[image]

When I am in Safari 9.1.1 the same page looks like:

[image]

The second image is the correct view. Size of the screen has no influence in the view. It works correct on my iPad. Not checked on iPhone.

Comment: That's a pretty big difference - I'd suggest first using something like the [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue have only reasons.

1) Might be there is some html break.
Solution > run the page in browser and view source code that check any where html code breaks or not if somewhere html closing tag missing it will create that type issue.

2) Might some where unnessory code write by mistake.
comma "," dot "." or any other special carckters put in css might be css not able to read by browsers. firefox and other browser read it but may be it is not readable for safari.

You can try above both of solution.

I hop this post will help you.